# Return data from jQuery promise object

Tags: jquery, getjson, promise

I am using `$.getJSON()` and trying to return data using various flavours of the code below:

```
 var changeUserPage = function (id) {
       return repository.getUserPage(id).done(function (data) {            
           // console.log(data)
       })
 }
```

The problem is that although inside the done function, I can see the correct data I want, I cannot return it to my calling function like:

```
 var data = dataContext.changeUserPage(lastPolicyWorkedOn);
```

data current holds the promise object:

```
Object {readyState: 1, setRequestHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, getResponseHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
```

EDIT

The getJSON method looks like:

```
var getUserPage = function (policyId) {
       policyId = encodeURIComponent(policyId);

       var uri = "http://localhost:54997/api/policy/getUserPage/" + policyId;
       return $.getJSON(uri);         
}
```

How do I best return the actual json data?

Thanks

Davy

Comment: hard to give solution with the current code posted. Can you plz post the getJson too?

Comment: @Jai. I've added the getJSON method.thanks

Comment: Okay now what are you expecting from that url?

Comment: If I uncomment the console.log(data) I can see that the json data is there and is as expected.  I son't know how to return that to the calling function.  Doe that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't be possible for `changeUserPage` to return the data, since the data is fetched using a `async` method `$.getJSON`.

Change

```
var data = dataContext.changeUserPage(lastPolicyWorkedOn);
```

to

```
dataContext.changeUserPage(lastPolicyWorkedOn).done(function(data){
    //do something with data
});
```

Comment: Thanks Arun for the clear answer.  I wanted to keep the 'promise' data away from the module where the calling code is but I guess that with my current design, I can't do that.  Thanks again.